# Is it possible to iterate  through a hash in sorted order using the while(my($key, $value) ... ) {} method?

Tags: perl, perl-data-structures

For a hash of this format:

```
my $itemHash = {
    tag1 => {
        name => "Item 1",
        order => 1,
        enabled => 1,
    },
    tag2 => {
        name => "Item 2",
        order => 2,
        enabled => 0,
    },
    tag3 => {
        name => "Item 3",
        order => 3,
        enabled => 1,
    },
    ...
}
```

I have this code that correctly iterates through the hash:

```
keys %$itemHash; # Resets the iterator
while(my($tag, $item) = each %$itemHash) {
    print "$tag is $item->{'name'}"
}
```

However, the order that these items are iterated in seems to be pretty random. Is it possible to use the same `while` format to iterate through them in the order specified by the 'order' key in the hash for each item?

(I know I can sort the keys first and then foreach loop through it. Just looking to see if there is cleaner way to do this.)

Comment: The `Tie::IxHash` module might be worth a look, though you would have to either change your code to insert into the hash in the order matching the 'order' key, or call the `Tie::IxHash` `Reorder` method sometimes to put everything in the right order.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The concept of an "ordered hash" is wrong. While an array is an ordered list of elements, and therefore accessible by index, a hash is an (un-ordered) collection of key-value pairs, where the keys are a set.

To accomplish your task, you would have to sort the keys by the `order` property:

```
my @sorted = sort {$hash{$a}{order} <=> $hash{$b}{order}} keys %$itemHash;
```

You can then create the key-value pairs via `map`:

```
my @sortedpairs = map {$_ => $itemHash->{$_}} @sorted;
```

We could wrap this up into a sub:

```
sub ridiculousEach {
  my %hash = @_;
  return map
      {$_ => $hash{$_}}
        sort
          {$hash{$a}{order} <=> $hash{$b}{order}}
             keys %hash;
}
```

to get an even-sized list of key-value elements, and

```
sub giveIterator {
  my %hash = @_;
  my @sorted = sort {$hash{$a}{order} <=> $hash{$b}{order}} keys %hash;
  return sub {
     my $key = shift @sorted;
     return ($key => $hash{$key});
  };
}
```

to create a callback that is a drop-in for the each.

We can then do:

```
my $iterator = giveIterator(%$itemHash);
while (my ($tag, $item) = $iterator->()) {
  ...;
}
```

There is a severe drawback to this approach: `each` only uses two elements at a time, and thus operates in constant memory. This solution has to read in the whole hash and store an array of all keys. Unnoticable with small hashes, this can get important with a very large amount of elements.

Comment: Yeah, "sorted hash" is probably not a good way to describe it, but I was trying to be concise in the title. Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

You can do some thing like :

```
foreach my $key (sort keys %{$itemHash}) {
    print "$key : " . $itemHash->{$key}{name} . "\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, so much nicer than the other answers!

Comment: This returns the order given by `tag1 -> tag2 -> tag3` but the question is to get order by `order => 1 -> order => 2 -> order => 3`. In this example they are the same, but could be different.

Answer (score 6):

The order in which keys from the hash is undefined.  So you'll need to sort the keys.  One way would be, as you stated, to pull the keys out and sort them, then loop through the keys.

Another way would be to sort them on the fly. I'm not sure you'd consider it cleaner though. Something like:

```
for my $key ( sort { $itemHash->{$a}{order} <=> $itemhash->{$b}{order} } keys %$itemHash ) {
  print "$key is $itemHash->{$key}{name}";
}
```

Comment: Yep. I knew about this method. I was wondering if there was short(er) hand way of doing the same with a `while` loop

Answer (score 2):

This will be quite cleaner. we have to use cmp for sorting strings.

> ```
> my $itemHash = {
>     tag1 => {
>         name => "Item 1",
>         order => 1,
>         enabled => 1,
>     },
>     tag2 => {
>         name => "Item 2",
>         order => 2,
>         enabled => 0,
>     },
>     tag3 => {
>         name => "Item 3",
>         order => 3,
>         enabled => 1,
>     }
> };
>
> foreach((sort{$a cmp $b}(keys(%$itemHash)))){
> print "$_ is $itemHash->{$_}->{'name'}\n";
> }
> ```